# Dynamically removing menu items: Dispose calls Remove

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My app dynamically adds/removes menu items at run-time.  My removal code looks like this:

```
while (menu.DropDownItems.Count > 0) {
    menu.DropDownItems[0].Dispose();
}
```

This works fine, because ToolStripItem.Dispose says `this.Owner.Items.Remove(this);` (verified with ILSpy).

My question is:  Is it good form to rely on the fact that ToolStripItem.Dispose also removes the item from the menu?  The [documentation for ToolStripItem.Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w536x3hd.aspx) does not mention this fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually the default behavior of the `Control` class, so it goes a bit further than just `ToolStripItem`.  I am using this method in my code as well.